# warning C4047: '=' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'

Tags: c, visual-c++, c99

What is the problem with the code shown below.

```
char filter[2] = {'\0'};
*filter = (char *)calloc((unsigned int)buf.st_size + 1, sizeof(unsigned char));
```

As per my understanding, there is no problem changing the array location right? Why I ask this is because of a warning,

```
Warning 1   warning C4047: '=' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
```

Any idea?

Got it, changed the code to. Thanks @ouah

```
char *filter = {'\0'};
filter = (char *)calloc((unsigned int)buf.st_size + 1, sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Comment: "As per my understanding, there is no problem changing the array location right?" There is, it's impossible. But that's not what the code is trying to do.

Comment: Now C or C++? If C, then don't case the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I meant to say, even though I allocated a two byte char array initially, I could allocate a chunk of memory later and point the array to it. Isn't it possible?

Comment: `char *filter = {'\0'};` -> `char *filter = NULL;`

Comment: @Aczire No. An array has fixed size and location. You can declare a pointer and `malloc/realloc` memory for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`*filter` is a `char` and you are assigning it a `char *` value.